# Pass encrypted querystring between php and asp.net (c#)

Tags: php, asp.net, query-string

I need to pass a single variable in a querystring from one application (in PHP) to another (in ASP.NET).  It's a one way transfer...That is I need to encrypt it in PHP and decrypt it in ASP.NET (c#).

I'm barely a newbie on PHP and I'd like not to have to do more than add a  tag to the page that needs to do the passing.

The data will be anywhere from 5 - 15 characters..only letters and numbers.

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to do more than that.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't understand your question...My question says it all.

I want to encrypt a querystring variable on the php side and decrypt it on the asp.net side.

It's low security

Anyway I figured it out

Comment: In the future, if you figure out an answer to your question, please post your solution so others don't have to post a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
<?
$query_string = base64_encode($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);

header("location: http://www.domain.com/page.aspx?query_string=$query_string");

//rest of php code...
?>
```

Then in page.aspx you decode that query string

Comment: That's not encryption, it is encoding. Not secure at all.